# Batch - run same command depending on the output

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I have a windows batch that knows to process 100 files at a time and move them somewhere after processing. (cannot be modified)

If process is unable to find any more files it return with "no more files"

If process was able to process it return with "process ok"

I want to run the process using a different batch file continually on folder with large amount of files 

How do I read and compare the value from the first batch to determine if I need to run the same command again?

 should i use GOTO or a while loop in this case?

```
do
   first batch
while (first batch output != 'no more files')
```

Comment: Why do you need to process 100 files at a time? It seems like `robocopy` would be a good solution because it has automatic retry, bandwidth limiting, etc.

Comment: batch exist and cannot be modified since its calling another system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
:do
   rem first batch
   for /F "delims=" %%a in ('firstBatch.bat') do set output=%%a
rem while (first batch output != 'no more files')
if "%output%" neq "no more files" goto do
```